# nServiceBus is not persisting to the MessageQueue

Tags: message-queue, nservicebus

I'm using nServivceBus to persist a message to the Message Queue. I've ran the runmefirst.bat. The messagequeue servivce is successfully installed. When I run the web application the private queues are successfully created.

When I send the message, it's not showing up in the Message Queue. No errors are thrown. I'm stumped.

**Setup**

```
    Configure config = Configure.WithWeb();
    config
        .StructureMapBuilder(Container)
        .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
        .MsmqTransport()
            .IsTransactional(true)
            .PurgeOnStartup(false)
        .XmlSerializer()
        .UnicastBus()
            .ImpersonateSender(false)
        .CreateBus()
        .Start();
```

**Config**

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="MsmqTransportConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqTransportConfig, NServiceBus.Core"/>
    <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core"/>
    <section name="MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig Queue="subscribe" />
  <MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="subscribe" ErrorQueue="error" NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="5"/>
  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Messages="Momntz" Endpoint="subscribe"/>
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

**Code**

```
private readonly IDocumentDatabase _database;
private readonly IBus _bus;

/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="HomeIndexCommandHandler"/> class.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="database">The database.</param>
/// <param name="bus"></param>
public CreateUserCommandHandler(IDatabases database, IBus bus)
{
    _database = database.RavenDb;
    _bus = bus;
}

/// <summary>
/// Executes the specified command.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="command">The command.</param>
public void Execute(CreateUserCommand command)
{
    var user = Mapper.DynamicMap<CreateUserCommand, User>(command); 
    user.AccountStatus = UserAccountStatus.Active;

    var foundUser = CheckForDuplicateUsername(user);

    if(foundUser != null)
    {
        throw new DuplicateUsernameException(string.Format("Username '{0}' already exists.", user.Username));
    }

    _database.Add(user);

    var denormalizeMessage = Mapper.DynamicMap<User, UserDenormalizeMessage>(user);
    _bus.Send(denormalizeMessage);
}
```

**update**

The intent is for a website to send messages to a message queue and a service to process the messages. It's very simple. I'm not looking for a response or communication between the client and server. It's one way communication.

Comment: I also am a little confused that you say you are *"using nServivceBus to persist a message to the Message Queue"*. The persisting of message to a MSMQ queue is a transport level detail rather than an end-game. What would be useful is if you told us what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using the same queue address for your input queue and for your message routing config:

```
<MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="subscribe" ...

and

<UnicastBusConfig>
  <MessageEndpointMappings>
    <add Messages="Momntz" Endpoint="subscribe"/> ...
```

This is not correct. The `MsmqTransportConfig` section defines your service's local input queue. The `UnicastBusConfig` section defines the destination addressing for sending messages.

Have you looked at the logfile which is generated by default by log4net? There will probably be some error information in there.

You also have defined a subscription queue:

```
<MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig Queue="subscribe" />
```

This suggests that you want your service to act as a publisher. In this case you would not use `Bus.Send()` but `Bus.Publish()`, and furthermore if this were the case then you would not need to add any routing information into the `UnicastBusConfig` section because this would be handled by the publish/subscribe functionality in NServiceBus.

Comment: thanks for taking a look. I'm new to nServiceBus and message based architecture. I've added an update to the post.